# Openfire 3.8.1 cannot open 'Admin Web Console'

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire, jive

I'm trying to install Openfire 3.8.1 in nginx server (Linux x86_64 - CentOs release 6.2 Final).

I run through the installation from this article [HERE](http://rricketts.com/install-openfire-3-8-1-on-centos-6-4-x86_64/) and I installed openfire using wget and yum successfully, then I change the network interface in /opt/openfire/conf/openfire.xml like this :

```
<network>
      <interface>myIPAddress</interface>
</network>
```

I also set my JAVA_HOME in /etc/sysconfig/openfire like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
```

Last step is to run command > sudo service openfire start

Output:

```
Shutting down openfire:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting openfire:
```

It's starting without errors...

Then I open web admin console http://x.x.x.x:9090, it is not opening and finally timeout like this:

```
The connection has timed out
The server at x.x.x.x is taking too long to respond.
```

I check the logs file in /opt/openfire/logs/error.log and warn.log, no errors/warns (empty file)
I also check nohup.out in /opt/openfire/logs/nohup.out, it said:

```
Openfire 3.8.1 [Sep 17, 2013 6:23:04 PM]
Admin console listening at http://x.x.x.x:9090
```

The admin is actually listening to the correct port that I specified, but the web console doesn't want to open the page... 
I've been installing and uninstalling openfire using various method for 3-4 times, but nothing works (always cannot open admin page)

I hope someone can help me, I'm really appreciated it... Really Thanks.

EDIT:

I read from Openfire forum (community.igniterealtime.org), they said I need to allow server firewall for certain ports, so I add it in etc/sysconfig/iptables like this:

```
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9090 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5222 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5223 -j ACCEPT
```

I restart/reload my openfire using command > sudo service openfire restart/reload

Same things happen, it's starting without errors and admin console page won't open

I check in my process using command > netstat -nap | grep 9090

Output

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:x.x.x.x:9090     :::*                        LISTEN      -
```

The output seems fine without errors because Openfire runs in other server with Ubuntu with this same output. Maybe Openfire cannot run in CentOs 6.2... I don't know... Please help.. I was going to give up at this state :(

I'm pretty clueless on what should I try again to fix this issue, the thing that I need the userservice secret key (in the web admin - userservice) to add new user with my integrated django-project. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

We had a similar problem with OEL 7.x and OEL 6.x. The OpenFire 4.5.2 console doesn't work in OEL 7.x but when we installed it in OEL 6.x, it worked.

Did you test in a previous CentOS version?

Best regard,

CB